# Meaning of the word "fold" in the sentence "Lamb astray from the fold"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Here's a extract from the fable "wolf and the lamb" from Aesop's Fables by George Townsend

> Wolf, meeting with a lamb astray from the fold...

In the above sentence what is meant by "fold"? Is it a flock of sheep?

Comment: Did any dictionary entries seem to explain this usage?

Comment: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/sheep-fold

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin No. The dictionary meanings do not seen to apply to context in which the word is used.

Comment: @Cascabel That definition of sheepfold sounds good.

Comment: Lexico has **fold**. Its [meaning #2](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/fold#h69951073150360) says "A pen or enclosure in a field where livestock, especially sheep, can be kept."

Comment: BTW it's not a "**heard** of sheep" or even a "**herd** of sheep" but a "***flock*** of sheep."*

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for correcting.

Comment: Somanna, if you add the dictionary reference you found (which didn't have the meaning you were after), it will show enough research.

Comment: @WeatherVane - So "shepherd" is invalid -- it should be "shepflock"??

Comment: @HotLicks nice idea, but the shepherd is a "sheep herder" so "herd" refers to the person not the animals. That person certainly is isn't a "sheep flocker", but this is getting a bit close to the bone... Anyway, it is the sheep who do the flocking.

Comment: @WeatherVane I am starting to hear "sheep-flocking", and "pheasant plucker"  bouncing around in my head...and it always comes out wrong.:-)

Comment: @Cascabel you at least managed to type them without erring. But next, we'll be saying "a **herd** of jubjub birds."

Comment: @WeatherVane  I have been told there is  new expression..."herding cats".  Wonderful imagery.

Comment: @Cascabel That would be clowdering them. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some will regard this question as reflecting "lack of research", but I consulted the common on-line dictionaries and a couple lacked the proper definition entirely, while others buried it at the bottom of the entry.

But here's a (rather well-concealed) definition from [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/fold) which fits pretty well:

> A fold is a fenced area on a farm where sheep are kept during the
>   night.